How to use azure devops authorization bearer token and clone a repo?
I am trying to clone a repo using an authorization bearer token I created using a service connection in Azure. The service principal has reader access to the repo I'm trying to clone. And in Azure I've given the following API permissions for the AAD app (since this didn't help I'm not sure if this is necessary):

Setup the default organization and project:
az devops configure --defaults organization="$org" project="$project"
$org is the azure devops organization and $project is the project where the git repo is.
Get the access token using the following command:
$token = az account get-access-token --resource "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798" --query "accessToken" --output tsv
The above steps are done in a powershell script which is run using AzureCLI@2 task in the pipeline. The obtained token is saved in git config using the following command:
git config --local http.<repo base URL>.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION bearer: $token"
When the git clone command is run, I get the following error:
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for '<repo URL>': No such file or directory

Any idea why I'm getting this error? Am I missing any steps?

Could you include what URL you are passing in ?

It has this format: https://<projectname>.visualstudio.com/

You can get the devops repo url following doc:

Steps below:

Create the service connection as you did, find the service principal and add it as contributor role +Basic access level of the target devops repo(if only clone the repo, project reader + basic access level permission is enough). So that the bearer token has permission to access the repo.

DevOps pipeline yaml sample below. set at git config at global level.


pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn1'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $token = az account get-access-token --resource "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798" --query "accessToken" --output tsv
      git config --global http.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $token"
      git clone https://<orgname>@dev.azure.com/<orgname>/<project>/_git/<reponame>



With regards to "add it as contributor role +Basic access level of the target devops repo" -- The service principal is added to a team which has "Reader" access to the project.

@yasouser, if you only clone the repo, read access of the project for the service principal is enough. Let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

The commands mentioned in the inlinescript is what I'm doing currently and I get "fatal: Authentication failed for ". I also tried that manually in powershell.

@yasouser, firstly follow the doc i shared above to confirm the repo url, if it's correct, add some output(eg: echo $token) in the script, is the $token fine? Also notice it's --global in git config. If you check from local, need to azure login with service principal az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <password-or-cert> --tenant <tenant> at the first step.

Hi @yasouser, may i know if there's any update? Please follow the steps for a check, it works for me, thanks.

It worked. I had to resolve some permissions issue in our internal systems. Instead of git config --global http.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $token", I did git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com/<orgname>/.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $token" to scope it down to the repo.

Glad to know it works, thanks for your sharing!  Happy coding!
